# Disguising URL by rewriting htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a site built for a client located on my server (ie http://www.myserver.com/clientsite). Can I disguise the URL by modifying the .htaccess file on my client's host (http://www.clientsite.com) to read as his domain, but display my content and keep the subdirectories in tact?

So: http://www.myserver.com/clientsite would read http://www.clientsite.com
and http://www.myserver.com/clientsite/about would read http://www.clientsite.com/about

I tried the following, but it was directing me to a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clientsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.myserver.com/clientsite/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?clientsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.myserver.com/clientsite/$1 [P]
```

Since you mentioned that your client's site is  **http://www.clientsite.com** and Rewrite condition was applied only to **clientsite.com** , I changed it to support both with and without www.

If it doesn't work, put your rewrite log and I'll check that.